# Django returns corrupted zip file

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

I wrote following code which fetches a data from db, forms two csvs, creates a zip containing both csvs and saves it to file system:

```
import csv
import io
import zipfile
from django.db import connection
from models import MyModel

myVal = 1019
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('''query''')
    query_result = cursor.fetchall()

all_rows_result = MyModel.objects.filter(col1=myValue)

# Create the zip file in memory
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w') as zip_file:
    # Create the query result CSV
    query_data_csv = io.StringIO()
    query_data_writer = csv.writer(query_data_csv)
    query_data_writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])
    for row in query_result:
        query_data_writer.writerow(list(row))
    zip_file.writestr('query_result.csv', query_data_csv.getvalue())

    # Create the all rows CSV
    all_rows_csv = io.StringIO()
    all_rows_writer = csv.writer(all_rows_csv)
    all_rows_writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])
    for row in all_rows_result:
        all_rows_writer.writerow([row.id, row.course_id, row.url, row.ip_address, row.date_visited, row.user_id])
    zip_file.writestr('all_rows.csv', all_rows_csv.getvalue())

with open('data.zip', 'wb') as zip_output:
    zip_output.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())
```

I ran above function and opened data.zip file. It contained two csv with desired data. The zip size was 4.1 kB. But when I opened, it shows one csv of size 2.0 kB and other of size 1.9 kB.

Then, I converted this to django REST endpoint:

```
import csv
import io
import zipfile
from django.db import connection
from models import MyModel
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_user_tracking(request):
    myVal = request.GET.get('my_val')

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('''query''')
        query_result = cursor.fetchall()
    
    all_rows_result = MyModel.objects.filter(col1=myValue)
    
    # Create the zip file in memory
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w') as zip_file:
        # Create the query result CSV
        query_data_csv = io.StringIO()
        query_data_writer = csv.writer(query_data_csv)
        query_data_writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])
        for row in query_result:
            query_data_writer.writerow(list(row))
        zip_file.writestr('query_result.csv', query_data_csv.getvalue())
    
        # Create the all rows CSV
        all_rows_csv = io.StringIO()
        all_rows_writer = csv.writer(all_rows_csv)
        all_rows_writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])
        for row in all_rows_result:
            all_rows_writer.writerow([row.id, row.course_id, row.url, row.ip_address, row.date_visited, row.user_id])
        zip_file.writestr('all_rows.csv', all_rows_csv.getvalue())


        # Set the appropriate HTTP response headers
        response = HttpResponse(zip_buffer.getvalue(), content_type='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.zip"'

    return response
```

Note that this code differs from first one at only two things: reading request and forming response. I hit this end point with postman. It downlaods the file of size 3.9 kB. But when I open it, it says "An error occurred while loading the archive".

I also tried with `content_type='application/zip'`. But it did not help.

What I am missing here?

Comment: You want to store data from databse into csv and then make archive of csv files and return in response am I correct?